# Adding contents of a String,where string s="12 computer 5 7"

Tags: java

In an interview they asked me this question.There is a string like "12 computer 5 7". You need to add integers within that string and answer should be 24.How can i solve this can anyone help me please.

string s="12 computer 5 7"

output should be:24

Can i use sub-string or some other process to solve it

Comment: You can split the string, and try parse everything in the array returned. When trying to parse "computer" you might get an exception, just handle it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
   String input = "12 computer 5 7";
    String[] splittedValue = input.split(" ");  // splitted the values by space

    int result = 0;
    for (String s : splittedValue)
    {
        if (s.matches("\\d+"))                 // check while the input is number or not
        {
            result = result + Integer.parseInt(s); // parse it and add it to the count
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Result  : "+result);
```

Comment: What exactly does the argument "\\d+" do?

Comment: @Riptyde4 it matches for any digit. Regex stuff I tell you xD

Comment: @Riptyde4 it checks the string should be number or not.

Comment: @Riptyde4 you want to add all the number of the given string so we split the string by space and then the splittedArray contains both the numbers and String values like computer. But we need only the numbers. Using //d it checks single digit number. using //d+ means takes multiple digits too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `split("[ ]")` to convert the string into an array of strings separated by space and then add the integers present in each position of the array. Add it to `sum` if it is an integer  like :-

```
String ar[] = s.split("[ ]");
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
   try{
        sum += Integer.parseInt(ar[i]);
   }catch(NumberFormatException){
      //not an integer.
   }
}

System.out.println("Sum of integers : "+sum);
```

Comment: @robin 12 + 5 + 7 = 24

Comment: :sorry got it, thats why deleted the comment. But before that you commented.

Comment: answer should be 24 that is what they asked.

Comment: @user3657497 , if you print sum, you get 24 as the output in console.

Comment: Great, that'll work for that exact string but not for "12 5 computer 7" or "abc 1 def 2 ghi 3 jkl". Also, why `split("[ ]")` instead of just `split(" ")`?

Comment: This will only work for the string that the OP used as an example. What if the string was "computer 12 13 lemons? Then your algorithm would be adding the ASCII value of computer, lemons, and 13.

Comment: @DavidConrad modified my answer. My answer was string specific

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String s="12 computer 5 7";
        String [] candidateNumbers = s.split(" ");
        int sum = 0;
        for (String num:candidateNumbers) {
            try {
               sum+=Integer.parseInt(num);
            } catch (Exception e) {
               // 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 you could also write:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\D+"))
           .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
           .sum();
```

Splitting on non digit characters returns an array containing the 3 numbers as strings. Note that this assumes that the input string is well formed.

Comment: int a[]={10,8,9,2,6,7,2,3,4,5,0};...find the second maximum ?

Comment: How is this related to your initial question?

Comment: Then you should ask a new question - this is not a forum.